# Network manager DNS settings

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn

I have my laptop connected to a wifi network that is `192.168.1.0/24`.  I then have that wifi adapter bridged to `br0`.  I then connect a tap-to-tap tunnel `tap1` onto a network that is `10.40.0.0/14`.

My wifi network has a DNS server at `192.168.1.254` while the remote network has a DNS server at `10.40.0.2`.  When the tap-to-tap tunnel comes up, I delete its default route so that only traffic to that network will go over the tunnel and general Internet traffic goes over the usual wifi link.  But I want to use the remote network's DNS server so that I can still look up local names on the remote network.

`nmcli device show wlan0` says this (I've removed various irrelevant bits for brevity, mostly ip6 and routing information):

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     channel-six
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.82/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.254
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.254
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.40.0.2
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          lan
```

This says that this device has both DNS servers assigned to it.  But `nmcli con show channel-six` says this:

```
connection.id:                          channel-six
connection.uuid:                        34402de9-ec2d-4a4e-a223-9bea7fc5b517
...
ipv4.dns:                               10.40.0.2
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       ""
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
```

So why is NetworkManager using the local DNS server?  How can I change it?

Answer (score 2):

The local DNS is being picked up from DHCP.  This can be fixed like this:

```
$ nmcli con modify channel-six +ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
$ nmcli con up channel-six
```

The `modify` command can also have `--temporary` added to make this a temporary change.  The `con up` is necessary to apply the change.